# How to create several temporary files with the same basename and a numbered ending using python?

Tags: python, temporary-files

I want to create temporary files and call a program to open them as a batch using python. However, this program requires the files to have a specific naming to be accepted as a batch:

> some_name_{number}.ending

Now I would like to use `tempfile.NamedTemporary` ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html)) for this, but it can only create one temporary file. I have a manual recipe (see below) but it is not secure (a lot could happen between the check whether the files exist and the actual creation).

```
from os import path
from glob import glob
import string
import random

def generate_files(dir, num_files, name_length=12, ending='.blob'):
    chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits        
    for i in range(1000):
        file_name = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(name_length))
        if not glob(path.join(dir, file_name)+"*"):
            return (file_name+'_{}'.format(number)+ending for number in range(num_files))
     raise RuntimeError('I give up, all filenames I tried already exist')
```

A sample usage is

```
>>> filenames = list(generate_files('.', 3))
>>> filenames
['9R3ZK913P39K_0.blob', '9R3ZK913P39K_1.blob', '9R3ZK913P39K_2.blob']
>>> # Now create the files
>>> # ...
```

**Questions:**

- Is there a library function that does this? (That would be the preferred answer)
- If no to the first question: How can the code above be improved in terms of avoiding file conflicts?

Comment: So you want to create 1000 or so empty files concurrently and then them to be deleted when done?

Comment: No the 1000 is just 1000 tries to create the files and to give up otherwise. I will adapt the example to make it more clear. For me the most important thing is that I am not overwriting files when creating them. Since between the glob check and a call to create the files there is the chance of another process creating a file which could be overriden then by me.

Comment: You cannot easily prevent this race condition from Python. You need atomic operations which can only realistically be provided by the OS, and will be platform-dependent.